# Dynamically position nested UL based on parent LI width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to implement the following effect

[image: Horizontally Stacked Nested UL Elements]

The HTML Code would like this:

```
    <ul class="product-selection"> 
        <li>
            <a href="#">Level One</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Level Two</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Level Three</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Each nested UL will be absolutely positioned from the left and I would like to set UL's Left value based on it's parent LI's width so that they appear right next to each other.

I was able to achieve this for the first nested UL with the following code, can someone please provide a better version of this.

```
var ulWidth = 0;
$j(function() {
    ulWidth = ulWidth + $j('ul.product-selection > li').width();
    $j('ul.product-selection > li > ul').css({'left': ulWidth});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution to my question:

```
 $j('.product-selection a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var prevLevel = $j(this).parents('.list-wrap').width();
  $j(this).next('.list-wrap').show();
  $j(this).next('.list-wrap').css({'left': prevLevel});
});
```